# Commutative diagram not working on tikzcd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm using the `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` and I'm trying to make a commutative diagram.

Why doesn't this simple code work?

```
$$ \begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow {rd}{f} \arrow{r}{\phi} & B \\ 
& C 
\end{tikzcd}
$$
```

I can't find a problem with this, but it won't compile?

Comment: if you get an error please post a small complete document and also show the exact error message from the log that you get from your test file.

Comment: No error if I add a standard preamble.